# Trying Laravel jetstream but getting an error on "npm run dev"

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix, laravel-jetstream

**lam getting the error below while running npm run dev**

[webpack-cli] TypeError: this.program.configureOutput is not a function
at new WebpackCLI (/home/vagrant/sites/ecom/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:19:22)
at runCLI (/home/vagrant/sites/ecom/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js:7:21)
at Object. (/home/vagrant/sites/ecom/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:23:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
at runCli (/home/vagrant/sites/ecom/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:54:2)
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/sites/ecom
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c mix

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-03-19T11_14_07_947Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/sites/ecom
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run development

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-03-19T11_14_07_974Z-debug.log

Comment: Have you updated your node.js?

Comment: Update your node.js and if you get the same error again replace the content of your package.json file with the content given below: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 1):

First, try to update your node.js file and then run "npm run dev" and if you again faced the same problem follow the following steps:

```
Step1: composer update
Step2: rm -rf node_modules
Step3: npm cache clear --force
Step4: npm install
Step5: npm outdated
In this step, it will update your laravel-mix version, it is in the package.json.
Step6: npm install
Step7: npm run dev
```

After all these steps, everything is good.
I hope it solve your problem.

Comment: It's better that way: npm cache clear --force

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when trying to build and run `webpack` (and `webpack-cli` locally), after check out from Github (not at all related to Laravel).

I found that I forgot to run `yarn install` for `webpack-cli` which lead to the issue that an existing version of `commander@6` was used, but `webpack-cli` requires `commander@7`.

`npm list commander` should tell you that the `webpack-cli` dependency is unsatisfied. `yarn install` should fix it.